# What is the meaning of "to look like a square"?

Tags: meaning, colloquialisms, phrases

I read this on [The Oatmeal](http://theoatmeal.com/blog/clapalong):

> Hey, he is clapping along to the music! How
>   quaint! I should too. I would not want
>   to **look like a square**!

Another one:

> You Won't **Look Like a Square** With
>   B-Side's Cubic, Steam-Punk Jewelry

(Emphasis added.) Now, what does it mean by looking *like a square*? Amazingly, Google doesn't know what that means.

Comment: Great Oatmeal btw; so true :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Google search for **define:square** gives me as one meaning

> a formal and conservative person with old-fashioned views

which is what "square" means in your example.

Comment: +1 for your answer, and thank you for the good chuckle `:)`

Comment: AKA "stick in the mud," a person who is no fun.

Answer (score 7):

It began in the 1960's (I believe, or possibly earlier) and is the opposite of being "hip" or "with it". There is a definite negative connotation which is missing from Ex-user's Google definition.

Comment: But later it became hip to be square ;)

Answer (score 4):

The antithesis of "hip".  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_%28slang%29) about it gets a bit rambling but captures the essentials.